# sum up value from textfile - bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to sum up the values in a textfile

try.txt

```
firstNumber,1
secondNumber,2
```

I tried with this script

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS, read -r -a array; do
     printf "%s %s\n" "${array[0]} ${array[1]}"
     for n in "${array[1]}"; do
        ((total += n))
        echo "total =" $total
     done
done < try.txt
```

and I landed up with this output

```
 firstNumber  1
 total = 1
 secondNumber  2
 total = 3
```

expected output

```
 firstNumber  1
 secondNumber  2
 total = 3
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not move your `echo` outside of your main loop?

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS, read -r -a array; do
     printf "%s %s\n" "${array[0]} ${array[1]}"
     for n in "${array[1]}"; do
        ((total += n))
     done
done < try.txt
echo "total =" $total
```

Comment: Oh no. It totally slip off my mind that I can just put in outside the loop. thanks alot by the way

Comment: There are a few problems here: `IFS,` should read `IFS=,` and what's the point of the `for n in "${array[1]}"; do ...` part???

Answer (score 4):

Try using `awk`. It's best suited for well formatted tabular data manipulation.

```
awk -F, '{total+=$2; print $1,$2} END {print "total = "total}' try.txt
```

Output:

```
firstNumber 1
secondNumber 2
total = 3
```